# Father with two children living in a remote house has a dog with a personality programmed in its collar

Tags: story-identification, movie

I believe this film had a father (tech guy) and two kids in a remote, tech modern house. Possibly post apocalyptic but not a real plot point. I want to say they had a dog with a nanny/dead mother programmed into its collar as a personality and the kids talked to it.

Two other kids showed up; maybe a boy and girl (boy possibly deaf or mute) and the family allowed them in. They brought with them bad adults at some point later. Murders and such start taking place. The deaf boy gets his throat cut in the kitchen by one of the homeowners kids.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: Sadly I was on a trip watching obscure indy films on a less than legal streaming site within the last 10 years.